# Is there a way to "link" facebook to your third-party website

Tags: facebook

I was wondering if there is a way to link your facebook account to another website, so you don't have to log in every time just to post a status update.

I'd like to link the profile when they sign up and then have it just be there to connect to whenever.

**CLARIFICATION: Sorry I typed this fast.. here's what I'd like to do.. build an application where you sign up for that application.. you also have the option to link your facebook profile to this account. If you decide to link it, you can post updates, etc to your facebook profile. 
You will never have to log into (connect) to facebook again after you link it to the app.. all you need to do is log into the third-party application.**

Thanks,
Matt Mueller

Answer (score 0):

Need clarification.  You can link logging into another website to Facebook.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I do not want the user to have to log into my app + facebook everytime. I would like them just to log into my app and have their facebook account linked to my app. One login essentially.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but the inverse is.  You can have them log into facebook and use this to authenticate and log into your app.  You might be able to do something with openID, but last time I looked at this you had to actually log into facebook regardless. http://developers.facebook.com/news.php?blog=1&story=246

Answer (score 0):

you question, to be honest isn't very clear, but maybe you need facebook restful api so check http://developers.facebook.com and look for it.

bye